# Button tag with javascript converted to link tag

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have a button tag the a 'submit' type and when clicked it executes javascript.

Button:

```
<button class="glossyBtn" type="submit" value="Cancel"  onclick="goBack(); return false;">
```

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function goBack() {
    window.history.back();
}
</script>
```

Save Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('form').submit(function () {
        $('#saveButton').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });
});
</script>
```

I want to change it to

```
<a class="glossyBtn" type="submit"> Cancel</a>
```

how can i make the link execute properly without using the button tag?

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you wanna do? You don't want to use javascript?

Comment: @MJQ no, OP doesn't want to use the `<button>` tag.

Comment: Well then wolfram has given the answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is how you would use javascript in a regular link.

```
<a href="javascript:goBack(); return false;" class="glossyBtn">Cancel</a>
```

EDIT: You can remove the type="submit" since it is no longer a button.

Comment: Thanks - this is working well. What if i have another form of script as i added above to my original question - Save Script. How can i add that to the href - just place a name to the function and call it?

Comment: That's right. You can use the same format in the href to call any javascript function you have. Likewise, you can call multiple functions in the same href.

Comment: still having some trouble with the second one so i created another question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11940773/trouble-calling-javascript-from-href

Answer (score 1):

The javascript works exactly the same

```
<a class="glossyBtn" onclick="goBack(); return false;" href="#">Cancel</a>
```

The href isn't actually used (the return false prevents it) but some browsers will style things not as you'd expect links if there is no href.

Note that I removed `type` as an attribute because this doesn't mean anything in HTML.

Also not that there may be accessibility issues with this since you have no alternative for those not running javascript. This is not a problem most peopel worry about these days though. :)