# Trouble calling javascript from href

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am having some trouble having my link function to execute javascript.

link:

```
<a class="glossyBtn" id="saveButton">Save</a>
```

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function (){
    $('form').submit(function () {
        $('#saveButton').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Though JQuery isn't my strongest point, it looks like the JQuery is waiting for your submit button to be pressed, not your link.

Comment: Where is the code that lets the anchor submit the form?

Comment: @Musa i changed my code to take out the button tag and replace with a link and i would like for the link to call the script and function but not really sure how to alter the script to suit the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('form').submit()` is fired when you submit a form (usually with `<button type="submit">`). Your button is not of submit type.

You may achieve it adding the following `onclick` to your `<a>` element: `onclick="$('form').sumbit();"` or add the following to your JS code

```
$('#saveButton').click(function{
   $('#saveButton').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
   $('form').submit();
})
```

Comment: yes i changed from button to link - i don't want to use the button tag.